# how to use jsPDF without pkg manager?

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

Tried this way: https://jsfiddle.net/wmefuraz/

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
```

but it said: Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined

What's the way to include and use withoyt nodejs? (working on a old project)

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to use most Node packages/libraries in the browser, so long as they're prepared for this. You can use Browserify, Webpack, or Rollup to help with this.

Another option is to check the GitHub page for the package/library to see if the developer already offers a browser-ready version of their component. In this case, yes, they do:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.1.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
```

You can include that `<script>` tag in your HTML to use jsPDF in your browser.

Please have a look at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) for jsPDF for further information.

Comment: but its exactly what I've done, if you check the fiddle. I've inserted https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.1.1/jspdf.umd.min.js, but when i run, it says Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined

Comment: My mistake. I did not see the resource loaded in the sidebar. Please try again using the following: `var doc = new jspdf.jsPDF();`

Comment: It's also worth noting that the method you're trying to use is deprecated as of the latest version of this library. https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/commit/533b8f09de42899dfe7a3d503a1451019bd7de49